# Default parameter in data class not converted to json using ktor serializer

Tags: kotlin, serialization, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I am facing a weird issue while serializing a data class to json in an http request.

Working code:

```
@Serializable
data class ComanyCustomerLoginData(
  val email: String,
  val credential: String,
  val companyUUID: String,
)
val customerLoginData = ComanyCustomerLoginData("trwla@gmail.com", "1234", "d80f0b72-a062-11eb-bcbc-0242ac130002")
val response = client.post<HttpResponse>(URL) {
   contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
   body = customerLoginData
}
```

Non working code

```
@Serializable
data class ComanyCustomerLoginData(
  val email: String,
  val credential: String,
  val companyUUID: String = "d80f0b72-a062-11eb-bcbc-0242ac130002",
)
val customerLoginData = ComanyCustomerLoginData("trwla@gmail.com", "1234")
val response = client.post<HttpResponse>(URL) {
   contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
   body = customerLoginData
}
```

In the non working code, in data class constructor there is one default parameter but when its serialized I don't see companyUUID in that json but working code creates a key named companyUUID.

can you please point out what is the issue?

Comment: Probably fields are just not serialized when they are equal to their default value, because it saves bandwidth. This might be configurable though

Comment: could be, will check. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Default values [are not encoded](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#defaults-are-not-encoded) by default in `kotlinx-serialization`:

[This place in the docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#encoding-defaults) describes how you can customize this behaviour:

```kotlin
val format = Json { encodeDefaults = true }
```

In the specific case of using this in Ktor, you can customize it this way:

```kotlin
install(JsonFeature) {
    serializer = KotlinxSerializer(kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
        encodeDefaults = true
    })
}
```

If both sides of the communication use the same data model, you shouldn't need this though. They will both use the default value properly and simply save bandwidth by not writing it explicitly.

---

EDIT: here is how you would configure this same thing in Ktor 2.0:

```kotlin
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json(Json {
        encodeDefaults = true
    })
}
```

See https://ktor.io/docs/serialization-client.html#register_json

Comment: Bless this dude

Answer (score 1):

You need `encodeDefaults = true`
See [this issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1154) for more information